# Can schema.org ReadAction be a URL where the book can be purchased?

Tags: schema.org, rich-snippets, rich-cards, readaction

1. [Google specifies](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/books) that [`ReadAction`](http://schema.org/ReadAction) is a required property for a valid [`workExample`](http://schema.org/workExample)
2. A valid `workExample` is a hardcover book.

Since you can't read a hardcover book online, does that mean that a valid value for the `urlTemplate` is just a URL where the book can be purchased?

Comment: I’m confused about your list (the title is clear to me, though). Where do you see a relation between `ReadAction` (which is a type, not a property) and `workExample` (which is a property)? Or do you mean the value which `workExample` can have (e.g., a `Book` item)? This `Book` can have a `potentialAction` property, which can be a `ReadAction` item.